# Validation Combobox CakePHP

Tags: php, mysql, validation, cakephp, cakephp-2.3

Hi I'm new using  CakePHP 2.6.3, I have a problem with the validation of some models.

I populate two different combo box with the same information, how can I validate that when I insert they don't have the same value.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

```
class Requisitoscurso extends AppModel {


public $validate = array( 
        'requisito' => array(
        'required' => array(
        'rule' => array('isUnique', array('requisito', 'cod_curso'), false), //sirve cuando se crea y no se pega con error, al editar deja repetir un requisito ya existente
        'message' => 'El requisito ya existe.')
        )
);
```

}

Comment: show us some codes you have

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe some custom validation like this:

```
public $validate = array(
    'someField1' => array(
        'rule' => array('cantBeSame'),
        'message' => 'someField1 cant be the same as someField2.'
    ),
    'someField2' => array(
        'rule' => array('cantBeSame'),
        'message' => 'someField2 cant be the same as someField1.'
    )
)

public function cantBeSame(){

    return ( $this->data['Somemodel']['someField1'] != $this->data['Somemodel']['someField2'] );

}
```